# How to handle this chili plant?

Tags: houseplants, harvesting, chili

This Chili was a present and i am not really good with plants actually they keep dying. But I want this one to stay alive. So I have the following questions.

[image]

1. What is this plant? (I know a Chili, but I guess there are different kinds of them)
2. How to handle this plant?
3. How do I know when I can harvest the Chilis?

I was told to water it twice a week. Still the leaves don't look healthy to me. Plus I put it into a new/bigger pot with fresh soil, maybe the pot is to big?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pot looks fine to me.

Peppers love the sun - so I would put it in a sunny window. (I live in Texas so I keep all mine outside, and plant most in the garden). If it is in a sunny location you might need to water it more often if it dries out.  A common symptom of erratic watering is "blossom end rot" where you get spots of rot on the fruit - you don't have any, but something to watch for.

Generally the leaves look fine - dark rich colour is good. Maybe some concern for the leaves that are slightly curled - sun & regular watering should fix any problems there (and twice a week sounds fine if it isn't drying out).

Variety: There are about 4 species and many hundreds of cultivars. You may never know. The upward pointing nature of the fruits hints at something like a *C.frutescens* cultivar (eg. like many ornamentals) but I don't think this matches the leaves, and most *C.frutescens* fruit are small. The majority of cultivars are bred from *C.annuum* (including bells and jalapenos). Pepper shape looks like many jalapenos and there are varieties of jalapenos with different colours.
Try one. If it is hot, then I would go for "probably a variety of jalepeno".

You can eat a pepper whenever you want. There are different colour varieties but a typical pepper forms as green and is ripe when red - but you can eat it when it is green.  The vast majority of green peppers in the grocers (including bells and jalapenos) aren't ripe! A ripe pepper will tend to be sweeter, but obviously people cook with unripe peppers for a slightly different taste.

As you have a few green and lots of orange, I think the orange are ripe. I would pick those soon.

Leaving too many peppers on a plant will inhibit further fruit formation. So I would pick them soon so you get more fruit, and before any pests come along and eat them for you.